# On points in the interior of planar convex regions and inscribed triangles

Tags: discrete-geometry, convex-geometry, plane-geometry

Given any planar convex region C, it is easy to show that every point in the interior C is the mid point of at least one chord of C. Likewise,

**Question:** Is every point in the interior of C the incenter of at least one triangle whose vertices are all on the boundary of C?

Note: Variants of the question can be got by replacing 'incenter' with other triangle centers.